# Summarise multiple columns in R using `case_when` and %in%

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data recording a feature (in the example below an animal) in the column name and a frequency in the cell values. I want to recode both of these into fewer categories, so that several of the columns are grouped into categories (in the example these are 'dogs' and 'birds'), and the frequencies are recoded as follows:

- If any of the original columns contain "Daily" or "Weekly" or "Monthly" → "Regularly"
- else if ≥one column is "Rarely" → "Rarely"
- else if ≥one column is "Never" → "Never"

It's proving tricky to work out since it's not simply averaging across the column values or taking the max value.

##### What I've tried so far

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~labrador,  ~beagle,    ~corgi,  ~pigeon, ~sparrow,   ~robin,
   "Weekly", "Rarely",   "Never", "Rarely",  "Never", "Rarely",
    "Never",  "Never", "Monthly",  "Never",  "Never",  "Never",
   "Rarely",  "Never",   "Never", "Weekly",  "Never",  "Daily"
  )

data %>% 
  mutate(dogs = case_when(
    c(labrador, beagle,  corgi) %in% 
      c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly") ~ "Regularly",
    c(labrador, beagle,  corgi) %in% 
      "Rarely" ~ "Rarely",
    c(labrador, beagle,  corgi) %in% 
      "Never" ~ "Never"
  )) %>% 
  mutate(birds = case_when(
    c(pigeon, sparrow, robin) %in% 
      c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly") ~ "Regularly",
    c(pigeon, sparrow, robin) %in% 
      "Rarely" ~ "Rarely",
    c(pigeon, sparrow, robin) %in% 
      "Never" ~ "Never"
  ))

#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `dogs`.
#> ℹ `dogs = case_when(...)`.
#> ℹ `dogs` must be size 3 or 1, not 9.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I'm guessing the error means that I'm doing something wrong with `case_when()` such that it's trying to pass 9 values to `dogs`. At the moment I'm trying to go through and check if any of the input columns has a certain value ("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" first), and assign the required grouping column value ("Regularly") for those three frequencies, and if not check if any of the input columns is "Rarely", etc.

##### What I am trying to achieve

Input data:

| labrador | beagle | corgi | pigeon | sparrow | robin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Weekly | Rarely | Never | Rarely | Never | Rarely |
| Never | Never | Monthly | Never | Never | Never |
| Rarely | Never | Never | Weekly | Never | Daily |

Desired output df:

| labrador | beagle | corgi | pigeon | sparrow | robin | dogs | birds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Weekly | Rarely | Never | Rarely | Never | Rarely | Regularly | Rarely |
| Never | Never | Monthly | Never | Never | Never | Regularly | Never |
| Rarely | Never | Never | Weekly | Never | Daily | Rarely | Regularly |

I want to keep the rows intact (the real data has columns with more information not included in the example), so a tally of the frequencies won't really help. And in the real data there are quite a few more columns and groups, but if I can work it out with the example I should be able to scale it up to that.

Comment: @r2evans in that case I'd want `dogs` to be "Regularly" – if it wasn't clear from the bulletpoint control flow, I effectively want the most frequent category to be assigned to the group

Comment: (Sorry, re-read, understood, and fixed, see my answer.)

Comment: I think `dplyr::if_any()` would be useful here (if you don't want to make a new function as in the given answer).  Example of use in your first "dogs" logic: `if_any(.cols = c(labrador, beagle,  corgi), ~.x %in% c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly")) ~ "Regularly"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
func <- function(..., values) {
  mtx <- do.call(cbind, list(...))
  mtx <- array(mtx %in% values, dim = dim(mtx))
  rowSums(mtx) > 0
}

data %>%
  mutate(dogs = case_when(
    func(labrador, beagle, corgi, values = c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly")) ~ "Regularly", 
    func(labrador, beagle, corgi, values = c("Rarely")) ~ "Rarely", 
    func(labrador, beagle, corgi, values = c("Never")) ~ "Never" ),
  birds = case_when(
    func(pigeon, sparrow, robin, values = c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly")) ~ "Regularly", 
    func(pigeon, sparrow, robin, values = c("Rarely")) ~ "Rarely", 
    func(pigeon, sparrow, robin, values = c("Never")) ~ "Never" )
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 8
#   labrador beagle corgi   pigeon sparrow robin  dogs      birds    
#   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 Weekly   Rarely Never   Rarely Never   Rarely Regularly Rarely   
# 2 Never    Never  Monthly Never  Never   Never  Regularly Never    
# 3 Rarely   Never  Never   Weekly Never   Daily  Rarely    Regularly
```

---

An alternative that does not require `func`, instead double-`pivot`ing.

```r
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
data <- mutate(data, rn = row_number())
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>%
  mutate(species = case_when(name %in% c("labrador", "beagle", "corgi") ~ "dogs", name %in% c("pigeon", "sparrow", "robin") ~ "birds", TRUE ~ "other")) %>%
  group_by(rn, species) %>%
  summarize(total = case_when(any(value %in% c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly")) ~ "Regularly", any(value %in% c("Rarely")) ~ "Rarely", any(value %in% c("Never")) ~ "Never", TRUE ~ "unk")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(rn, names_from = species, values_from = total) %>%
  left_join(data, ., by = "rn")
# # A tibble: 3 x 9
#   labrador beagle corgi   pigeon sparrow robin     rn birds     dogs     
#   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <int> <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 Weekly   Rarely Never   Rarely Never   Rarely     1 Rarely    Regularly
# 2 Never    Never  Monthly Never  Never   Never      2 Never     Regularly
# 3 Rarely   Never  Never   Weekly Never   Daily      3 Regularly Rarely
```

Comment: For a built-in function I think `dplyr::if_any()` could work in place of `func()` here since it outputs one logical value across the columns. I didn't check thoroughly, but see, e.g., `if_any(.cols = c(labrador, beagle,  corgi), ~.x %in% c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly")) ~ "Regularly"`